# Getting META description via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Let's say I do a simple AJAX request (in jQuery) like `geturl.php?url=http://google.com`

and `geturl.php` is this:

```
<?php
    if($_GET['url'])
    {
        $url=$_GET['url'];
        echo file_get_contents($url);
    }
?>
```

Simple, right?

How would I grab the META description from the returned (really long) string in jQuery?

Here's what I have so far. Yes, I know, `desc` is wrong.

```
$.get("geturl.php?url="+url,function(response)
{
    // Loading <title></title>data
    var title=(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(response)[1];
    var desc = $("meta[name=description]").val();
    $("#linkbox").html("<div><b>"+title+"</b><br/>"+url+"<br />Desc: " + desc)
});
```

Comment: Do you need only the description? Because then you could parse it in PHP

Comment: I'm with @Pekka; do this server side. And also: [regexps, HTML, parsing, don't... you know the drill](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/147845).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions to parse HTML is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Annoyingly, jQuery doesn't support parsing elements in the `head`, only the `body`. So use straight JS instead:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET', 
          url: '/',
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(data) {

            //cross platform xml object creation from w3schools
            try //Internet Explorer
              {
              xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
              xmlDoc.async="false";
              xmlDoc.loadXML(data);
              }
            catch(e)
              {
              try // Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
                {
                parser=new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
                }
              catch(e)
                {
                alert(e.message);
                return;
                }
              }

            var metas = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("meta");
            for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
              if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == "description") {
                alert(metas[i].getAttribute("content") || metas[i].getAttribute("edit"));
              }
            }
          }
    });
  }
```

Shamelessly ripped from [David Burrows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069953/1122351). Thanks, David!

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wCL8W/8/

Comment: why didn't you just use `jQuery.parseXML` ? :P

Comment: jQuery.parseXML will attempt to parse the document as well-formed XML, which will almost always fail :P

Answer (score 12):

While the answer by primatology does work, the statement about jQuery is wrong. A DOM is a DOM. jQuery does not care about whether we're looking for a `<head>` or `<body>` element. The following works just fine:

```
$('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
```

Just make sure you call the function after the meta-tags have been loaded.

The error in the OP is the use of the `val()` function, which is used to get the value of a `value` attribute in form elements. But since the value of a meta tag lies in a `content` attribute, it does not work.