# Remove meta tag with parent paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

i wanted to remove meta tag with parent paragraph tag in below code.

```
<p>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=unicode" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</p>
<p>
    <meta content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.18702" name="GENERATOR" />
</p>
<div>
    <img border="0" src="http://localhost:15978/TestImages/Que_152_0/51099.jpg" /></div>
<br />
<br />
<div>
    write something on the pic shown.</div>
```

I can remove meta tag using

```
.replace(/<meta([^>]+)>/g, '');
```

regular expression, wanted regular expression to replace meta with parent paragrapy tag

Comment: @badZoke, No, anything which replaces meta with parent paragraph tag using JavaScript or jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished with this short jQuery command:

```
$('p meta').remove();
```

Finding `<meta>` tags that are children of `<p>` is easily described in a selector, and `remove()` will remove all matching elements at once.

It becomes a bit more complicated when your HTML is in a string, but it's still not too bad:

```
var content = '...insert above html here...';

// insert into a div to parse as HTML
var $content = $('<div />').html(content);

// find all <meta> tags inside <p> and remove them
$content.find('p meta').remove();

// convert contents back to a string
content = $content.html();
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WVWPS/

Although the above code works for me, there may be problems in some browsers caused by the fact that `<meta>` is not a valid HTML element in the body of a document. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034881/what-is-the-best-practice-for-parsing-remote-content-with-jquery) suggests that jQuery may not be able properly create elements like `<meta>` in some cases.

If you run into browser-specific problems, you can try something like this:

```
var content = '...insert above html here...';

// convert <meta> tags to <span> tags with a "meta" class
content = content.replace(/<meta /g, '<span class="meta" ');

// insert into a div to parse as HTML
var $content = $('<div />').html(content);

// find all .meta elements inside <p> and remove them
$content.find('p .meta').remove();

// convert contents back to a string
content = $content.html();
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4Wa3/

Before we parse the HTML, we're doing a string-replace to convert the `<meta>` tags into `<span class="meta">` tags instead.

Note that this last option is a very fragile solution, and could break if you change how the meta tags are generated. As a general rule, manipulating HTML with regular expressions or other string functions should be avoided, as it can have [serious side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: i wanted to remove tag from string not from HTML element

Comment: @HaneepCR I've updated my answer to address working with a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in jQuery,

```
$("meta").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parents("p").length > 0) {
        $this.remove();
    }
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/tTLmt/1/)

Comment: i wanted to remove tag from string not from HTML element