# How do you set the URL of the document being referenced in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract some basic information from a website, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the document "source" as the website I'm referencing. For example, if I have something like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var user = document.getElementById("the-user").innerHTML
</script>
```

How can I make it so that the script knows which document to take the ID from (in this case a website that I own)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to retrieve the content from the remote URL and then parse this content as HTML. For this part, I'll refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069953/1226267

When you have retrieved and parsed the content, you'll be able to use it like this:

`var user = xmlDoc.getElementById("the-user").innerHTML`

(where `xmlDoc` is the variable that you stored the parsed content in, this variable name is also used in the referred answer).