# Better jQuery Ajax error information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When do a `jQuery.ajax` call, and it fails, the function assigned to the `error` option provides very sparse error information, yet when I use Chrome developer tools, the network tab, I see the response includes an HTML document with a much more verbose and informative explanation of the error.

Can I get this kind of error information back from the `$.ajax` call, and if so, how?

Comment: Is this error manually generated by your backend? What kind of error would have HTML included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$.ajax({ cache: false,
    url: "/Admin/Contents/GetData",
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    document.body.innerHTML = jqXHR.responseText;
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Aj7Tgxxno9fCcYBlwKuJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jqXHR responseText property, it will use the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object and you can get the full response body.

```
$.ajax(url).fail(function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(errorThrown);
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 0):

The `error` callback in jQuery gives the XMLHttpRequest object as the first parameter.

Use `xhr.response` or `xhr.responseText` to get the full error page.

```
$.ajax({
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        xhr.response;
    }
});
```

For information on how to parse the response, see [What is the best practice for parsing remote content with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034881/5743988)

Answer (score -2):

```
   var printError = function( req, status, err ) {
  console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
};

// Create an object to describe the AJAX request
var ajaxOptions = {
  url: '/data/people.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: your function,
  error: printError
};
```

I think this is a better approach.

Comment: It's the bad solution I'm trying to improve on. It hardly gives any info, where the HTTP response to the `$.ajax` call includes a nice and verbose explanation of the error and even possible causes. That is the whole purpose of my question: how to get the info in that HTML document.