# Error information in jQuery Ajax Deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-ajaxq

I'm using jquery 3.3.1 and jqueryui 1.12.1

In a simplified version of my code I have this, which seems to be very similar to the idiom in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352323/better-jquery-ajax-error-information)

```
 var deferred = $.ajax({
        "url" : url,
        "type": 'GET',
        "data": parameters
    });

 deferred.fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
```

However the parameters received by my fail function don't have the expected content.

The first parameter I receive has no `responseText`, and in fact seems to be a `deferred` object. The `textStatus` has a simple String: `"error"` and `errorThrow` an empty string: `""`

Obviously in my real code I have a `done()` method as well, and that works just fine.

I'm running in Chrome if that is relevant. I would really like to have some better error reporting.

Comment: you must to send form back-end  and get in success

Comment: @Wara Hall, I don't think this is right. You are referring to the long-standing way of using $.ajax that exploits success() and error() callbacks, for error handling in that case we would use the error() callback. There is a new style that exploits Deferred and Promises - the $.ajax() call returns a deferred object. I want to use this newer style; it has advantages for more complex scenarios. I am asking about error handling in this newer style.